# Regular Expression to detect URL without http or www

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I am trying to detect URLs and replace it with hyperlink when a user types in a textarea. I am trying to test the string for URLs using regular expressions:

```
var text='gggg.com/gd/';
var exp = /(\b(https?|ftp|file):\/\/[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|])/ig;
var text1=text.replace(exp, "<a href='$1'>$1</a>");
var exp2 =/(^|[^\/])(www\.[\S]+(\b|$))/gim;
var finalText=text1.replace(exp2, '$1<a target="_blank" href="http://$2">$2</a>');
alert(finalText);
```

It works fine for URLs with parameters with ot without http(s) but fails to recognize URLs without http and www e.g. abc.com or anc.com/fgdg/dgd or abc.com?lklkj=kjhkjh

**Update**

Based on the comment by [epascarello](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14104/epascarello) and the answer by [Ali Khan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3952581/ali-khan):

```
var text='gggg.com?klk=efhjsk';
var exp2 = '^([a-zA-Z0-9]+(\.[a-zA-Z0-9]+)+.*)$';

var pattern1 = /^([a-zA-Z0-9]+(\.[a-zA-Z0-9]+)+.*)$/;

if(pattern1.test(text) && text.substr(0,3)!='www'){
    var finalText = '<a href="'+text+'" target="_blank">'+text+'</a>';
}else{
var exp = /(\b(https?|ftp|file):\/\/[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|])/ig;
      var text1=text.replace(exp, "<a href='$1'>$1</a>");
      var exp2 =/(^|[^\/])(www\.[\S]+(\b|$))/gim;
      var finalText=text1.replace(exp2, '$1<a target="_blank" href="http://$2">$2</a>');
}
alert(finalText);
```

Comment: because your regular expression requires it to be there, you would need to make that part conditional.

Comment: So, I should first check for the pattern abc.xyz, if not then the remaining patterns?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
^([a-zA-Z0-9]+(\.[a-zA-Z0-9]+)+.*)$
```

Comment: the following regex will make  http://, https://, ftp:// and www. optional 

    @"^((http://|https://|ftp://|)(www.|)[a-zA-Z0-9]+(\.[a-zA-Z]+)+.*)$"